# Windows 8.1 winform menus are very bright

Tags: windows-8.1, winforms

recently I've noticed some of my Winform menus have turned very white [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxDda.png). How can I fix it?

Comment: This indicates to me you have either installed a program that modified that menu incorrectly or you have a system corruption problem.  Is it only that program or all programs?

Comment: It happens with all winform menus..